# Vulkan output RGBA color to BGRA color attachment

Tags: graphics, vulkan, freeimage

I wrote a simple Vulkan demo with BGRA images queried from swapchain. If I output RGBA pixels to it, the R channel and G channel in final result were swapped.

But when I checked the demo in Vulkan SDK dir, I found that it also use a BGRA image view for color output (I checked this in code and RenderDoc), but the final result is correct!

So, when did the conversion happen? Did I miss something?

**vulkan demo output**

[image: vulkan demo output]

**Vulkan demo has a BGRA format output**

[image: vulkan demo has a BGRA format output]

**My poor result**

[image: my poor result]

**Edit:**

Sorry about the lack of the code. The first answer gave me a hint to find the real problem in loading image from disk by **FreeImage**. Images it loads are stored as **BGRA** format with default setting on windows:

[image]

Thanks for your help and advice, @opa and @solidpixel.

Comment: With out code, we cannot help you, your question  may eventually get closed and flagged if changes are not made to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either setting up your texture reads incorrectly, or you're setting up your swapchain writes incorrectly. If I had to guess you're uploading data into the wrong texture format, but without a complete example it's hard to tell.

Comment: As it stands, this would work much better as a comment than an answer, answers should be useful in their own right, and this one just isn't.

Comment: Well, given the OP mentioned that the swapchain was the same setup as an example that worked the probability is that the texture reads are the problem. Still, will post as a comment next time ...